# какие виды бана бывают?

Tags: php, javascript

Мне как начинающему веб разработчику стало интересно,какие виды бана бывают.
знаю что есть по ip (на мой взгляд , он самый мощный), может кто то дать более детальную инфу, какие есть виды и какой самый надёжный бан для сайта?

Comment: опишите вашу проблему более конкретно, иначе вопрос слишком общий. Какую задачу вы решаете, кого банить собираетесь,  с какими условиями, на какой срок, как это отслеживать будете. Заблокировать доступ оп IP конечно можно, но большинстве случаев помимо злодея это заблокирует и еще пару-тройку тысяч возможных пользователей. Роскомнадзор вот имеет широкую практику запрещения доступа к сайтам по IP адресам, блокируя вместе с одним сайтом все плошадку.

Comment: ну вот например недавно,мой друг столкнулся с ситуацией,его забанили на сайте,но стоило ему залезть на сайт с другого браузера и сайт снова для него работает

Comment: Поэтому я и заинтересовался этим вопросом,как это работает?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию

Comment: Бан — очень размытое понятие.  Сравнивать размытые понятия — дело сомнительной полезности. Расскажите лучше, какую задачу вы решаете.

Comment: @NickVolynkin предположу что все же дело не в виде бана, а в том, какие способы есть  для определения одного и того же пользователя на ресурсе (куки, ip, браузер, макадрес, размер экрана, их микс и прочее), чтобы, если это злостный нарушитель, принять соответствующие меры........ а тема, кстати, интересная

Comment: @teran ↑ ↑ ↑ ...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в такой постановке вопроса — да, интересная.

Comment: Попадается забавная механика – теневой бан. Когда забаненный не замечает бана, но для всех остальных участников исчезает.

Comment: @ПавелШиляев если вы имели в виду в вопросе то же, что я описал в комментарии, то рекомендую отредактировать вопрос, внести правки, дописать об этом. В общем, привести в порядок и уточнить. А то сейчас он выглядит странно и непонятно. Именно поэтому он временно закрыт